# Flutter Riverpod not rebuilding after reordering a list

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm doing a todolist with riverpod. I have a ReordorableListView that contains tasks. When I drag and drop a task to reorder it, I'm calling a function to reorder them (updateTasksOrder).

The algo is good but it's **not rebuilding the lis**t. For example, if I delete the task, this one is deleted on screen. **It looks like Riverpod don't care about the new order in the list**. I used a setState additionally (part in comment in the function) and it works but I guess that's not the right way to do it.

Can someone help me? :)

```
// all tasks
final tasksProvider = NotifierProvider<TodoList, List<Task>>(TodoList.new);

// to do, in progress or done
final taskTypeProvider = StateProvider<TaskType>((ref) => TaskType.todo);

// return tasks by type (to do, in progress or done)
final filteredTasks = Provider<List<Task>>((ref) {
  final filter = ref.watch(taskTypeProvider);
  final todos = ref.watch(tasksProvider);

  switch (filter) {
    case TaskType.todo:
      return todos.where((task) => task.type == TaskType.todo).toList();
    case TaskType.inProgress:
      return todos.where((task) => task.type == TaskType.inProgress).toList();
    case TaskType.done:
      return todos.where((task) => task.type == TaskType.done).toList();
  }
});
```

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // filtered tasks
    final tasks = ref.watch(filteredTasks);

    void updateTasksOrder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
      // task that has to move
      final Task taskToMove = tasks[oldIndex];

      // task that has the wanted index
      final Task taskBefore = tasks[newIndex];

      ref.watch(tasksProvider.notifier).reorder(taskBefore: taskBefore, taskToMove: taskToMove);

      // setState(() {
      //   tasks.removeAt(oldIndex);
      //   tasks.insert(newIndex, taskToMove);
      // });
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('To Do List')),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("To Do"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      ref.watch(taskTypeProvider.notifier).state = TaskType.todo;
                    }
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("In Progress"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      ref.watch(taskTypeProvider.notifier).state = TaskType.inProgress;
                    }
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("Done"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      ref.watch(taskTypeProvider.notifier).state = TaskType.done;
                    }
                  )
                ]
              ),
                SizedBox(
                height: 500,
                child: ReorderableListView(
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => updateTasksOrder(oldIndex, newIndex),
                  children: [
                    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) ...[
                      ProviderScope(
                          key: ValueKey(tasks[i]),
                          overrides: [
                            _currentTask.overrideWithValue(tasks[i]),
                          ],
                          child: const TaskItem()),
                    ]
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Task{
  final String id;
  String description;
  TaskType type;

  Task({
    required this.description,
    required this.id,
    this.type = TaskType.todo,
  });
}

class TodoList extends Notifier<List<Task>> {
  @override
  List<Task> build() => [
    Task(id: 'todo-0', description: 'Task 0'),
    Task(id: 'todo-1', description: 'Task 1', type: TaskType.inProgress),
    Task(id: 'todo-2', description: 'Task 2', type: TaskType.done),
    Task(id: 'todo-3', description: 'Task 3'),
    Task(id: 'todo-4', description: 'Task 4')
  ];

  void remove(Task target) {
    state = state.where((task) => task.id != target.id).toList();
  }

  void reorder({required Task taskBefore, required Task taskToMove}){
    state.remove(taskToMove);
    int beforeIndex = state.indexOf(taskBefore);
    state.insert(beforeIndex, taskToMove);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reorder function is mutating state, not replacing it completely.  You need to update the identity of state in order for it to trigger an event to be emitted.

Comment: Thank you for being so fast. But it's not working... Even if I change the description of the task it changes it on screen but the position is still the same (when I print the list in console the list is reorderd and when I rebuild it manually by changing my type of tasks it works too).

Comment: I can't make further comment until you show the code that you've changed.

Comment: `void reorder({required Task taskBefore, required Task taskToMove}){
    state.remove(taskToMove);

    taskToMove.id = uuid.v4();

    int beforeIndex = state.indexOf(taskBefore);
    state.insert(beforeIndex, taskToMove);

  }`

Comment: Actually I'm just using the order of my list to order them. Should I add an `orderIndex` property to my Task class?

Comment: Your code is mutating state, not replacing state.  I don't see something that looks like "state = f(state)".

Comment: Now I get it! :) Thanks a lot for your explanations